# Adding a generic type constraint halfway through a method

Tags: c#, generics

I have two generic methods -

```
public CustomObject<T> MethodA<T>(T arg1) where T : class
{
    ...
    return MethodB<T>(arg1);
}


public CustomObject<R> MethodB<R>(R arg2) where R : class, IInterface
{
    ...
    return new CustomObject<R>();
}
```

The problem is clearly that I can't call `MethodB` with a type that doesn't implement `IInterface` (which T doesn't). But what if I did this -

```
public CustomObject<T> MethodA(T arg1) where T : class
{
    ...
    var casted = arg1 as IInterface;
    if (casted != null)
    {
        return MethodB<T>(casted);
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't compile, yet it should, no? How can I let the compiler know that I know that `casted` implements `IInterface` and is a class so the call to `MethodB` is fine? The big wrinkle in here is probably that I'm trying to return `CustomObject<T>`.

Comment: Whoops, I messed this up a bit. Gimme a min to rewrite it.

Comment: You've got two choices.  Either remove the class constraint on MethodB or add the IInterface constraint to MethodA

Comment: Unfortunately the circumstances mean that I can't do either of those. There's no way to "add" the information that T implements IInterface at this point in the method?

Comment: Can you please give some more concrete examples of why you need this structure? It's hard to know if there could be a completely different, but valid answer without a more familiar context arising from an understanding of what your methods do, or what the class these methods are in does, etc.

Comment: @ErikE sure, the situation is that I have a number of entities that implement an interface "IActivatable". This interface includes two props - a start and end date. Before I create/update entities I run the appropriate business logic rules against them. In this case I wanted to add some business logic that, for every entity that implements IActivatable, would check that the start date is before the end date. MethodB is that check.

Comment: Why is it that only some objects are IActivatable and others are not in MethodA?

Comment: Because not all objects that I'm running business logic against need "startdate" and "enddate"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because your `CustomObject<T>` is generic, it's problematic. For example, `CustomObject<object>` is not interchangeable with `CustomObject<string>`, but you can convert between the two.

You could do this as a workaround:

```
public class CustomObject<T> where T : class {}
public interface IInterface { }

public static class CustomObjectConverter
{
    public static CustomObject<T1> ConvertTo<T1, T2>(CustomObject<T2> other)
        where T1 : class
        where T2 : class
    {
        return new CustomObject<T1>();
    }
}

public CustomObject<T> MethodA<T>(T arg1) where T : class
{
    if (arg1 is IInterface inf)
    {
        var b = MethodB(inf);
        return CustomObjectConverter.ConvertTo<T,IInterface>(b);
    }
    return null;
}
public CustomObject<T> MethodB<T>(T arg2) where T : class, IInterface
{
    return new CustomObject<T>();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it makes `T` in `MethodB` always `IInterface` - it's never the actual type of the object. It's the same as making the signature `CustomObject<IInterface> MethodB(IInterface arg2)`

Comment: Thanks... let me check

Comment: @Nick I think he's right I can't delete my answer until you unaccept it.

Comment: I'm not sure you should delete it - this actually worked for me. I was able to convert the CustomObject<IInterface> that came back from MethodB into a CustomObject<T>. I'm not sure I understand Enigmativity's objection - I was still able to call MethodB despite it's "class" generic constraint.

Comment: OK that bit was fine, my note about doing a cast was wrong.

Comment: @Nick If that's the case then *the method shouldn't be generic in the first place*, because you always want to provide the interface as the type.  Just remove the generics and use the interface wherever you were using the generic type argument.

Comment: @MineR If you believe that your own accepted answer is wrong, you can flag it and ask a moderator to delete it.  Just explain that it's accepted, but you've since realized that the answer is wrong.  Moderators will honor such requests as long as they believe that you're not intentionally vandalizing your own content, which should be clear in this case.

Comment: @Servy that might be true in some cases - this example doesn't quite capture the complexity of what is actually going on in my code. In my case MethodB must be generic. If you all believe that the reflection answer is better given the spirit of the question then I can change it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use reflection to make this work.

Try this:

```
public CustomObject<T> MethodA<T>(T arg1) where T : class
{
    if (arg1 is IInterface)
    {
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("MethodB").MakeGenericMethod(arg1.GetType());
        return (CustomObject<T>)method.Invoke(this, new [] { arg1 });
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Enigmativity I like this answer but @MineR's happens to make more sense for my use case. That's why I accepted his. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: @Nick - MineR's solution doesn't work though. It makes the `R` in `MethodB` always `IInterface` and never the actual type of the object.

Comment: Just remember... reflection is slooooowwwww.

Comment: @ErikE - It only matters if it is too slow. And speed doesn't seem to stop people putting copious numbers of `try`/`catch` blocks in code. Speed is only important when slowness becomes an issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity I wasn't suggesting he not use reflection. I was suggesting he *remember* that it is slow, and not design a system where as it grows and reaches tipping points, what used to be acceptable speed turns into a nightmare. Speed is always important to *some* degree, insofar as speed is part of our basic operating parameters and SLA. If one knows that this method is going to be called many times, it's really unwise to do this reflection here. Maybe the application at deployment only has 1,000 data points, but in 1 year it will have 1,000,000. That is simple planned obsolescence.

Comment: @Enigmativity In the same article where Donald Knuth said "premature optimization is the root of all evil" (in the context of goto statements saving tiny percentage points of performance), he was strongly in favor of a 12% performance improvement. Reflection takes on order of 25-30 times as long to perform the same operations! Shouldn't people be aware of this and keep it in mind as they choose their architecture? Not all systems can easily be optimized later, if they were designed naively with no care to real-world constraints.

Comment: @ErikE - You're arguing my point. You're worrying about "premature optimization". Don't worry about reflection until it is a problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am not worried. You are oblivious. You are acting as if I said he has to do anything. You are allergic to the *very idea* of even **thinking** about performance. It is a flaw.

Comment: @ErikE It's not really appropriate to consider the performance difference in percentages in cases like this.  The overhead of invoking a method without reflection is approximately zero.  It's almost immeasurably small.  Using reflection to call a method is *very, very* fast, but just not *infinitesimal*.  That results in it being a significant *percentage* higher, but still a very small absolute value.  As long as this code doesn't make up a significant percentage of the OP's application, that's not a problem.  Increasing .0001% of your application's code by 30x is nothing.

Comment: @ErikE So using reflection here is only really a problem *if running this method is a large portion of what their program is doing*.  But even more importantly than that, to say that this solution is slow *you need to compare it to something*.  The problem the OP is asking to solve *is inherently dynamic*, and can't be solved with static typing.  You can't say a solution is slow unless you have a faster *working* solution.

Comment: @Servy proof you are not thinking clearly. I said reflection is slow, not this solution. Have you asked if this code will be run in a loop or otherwise thousands of times? No. So you are speaking without certainty. In my experience developers who are new to reflection often misuse it. They need to think about it.

Comment: @ErikE If you think reflection is slow but this solution isn't, then I guess you think that this solution isn't using reflection, in which case, why are you talking about it.  You're the one asserting that there is an important performance problem that needs to be addressed here.  For such an assertion to be valid, you need to know that this code is run a *lot*.  If you don't know that, your assertions aren't valid.  So *you* are the one who needs to ask the OP how the method is used for your statements to be valid.

Comment: @Servy You’re still treating my statement as one that MUST apply to the solution. All I meant is that reflection is slow *compared to normal invocation*. I credited the reader (answered? OP?) enough experience and knowledge to decide for himself if that matters. If 30x cost for reflection makes no difference to him, it’s fine. If it does, then he’s aware it may need some caching mechanism. Do you think people should just blindly use answers with no awareness of potential pitfalls? One code fits all? My statement is factual and needs no inquiry for me to say it. People interpreted more.

Comment: @ErikE Saying, "this solution is slow compared to a solution that doesn't work" doesn't really mean much.  It's what it takes to solve the problem.  Additionally saying, "this is several times slower than something that takes an almost immeasurably small amount of time, and is therefore *incredibly* small as well, makes your statements rather misleading.

Comment: @Servy I credit readers with enough wit to know that working is better than not working. Then anyone can ask: how can I make it faster—I’ll be using this in a tight loop. Answer: caching techniques and concurrency-safe dictionaries.

Comment: @ErikE Yes, if someone *has run the code and determined that there is a performance problem*, that that could potentially make for a good question related to how to address it.  But they didn't.  You just said that the answer is slow and insults the author and me for saying that there's no indication that it's it won't perform suitably, and that performance problems should be addressed when that is indicated as being a measured problem.  Additionally whether caching is actually a feasible option, or if it would help, is highly context dependent, it's plausible that it isn't.

Comment: @Servy Sigh. I did not say the answer is slow. I said reflection is slow. And as I said, I meant compared to direct invocation. Why are you so upset about that? As for caching—I meant caching the reflection-based method creation per type. Did you think I meant caching output values?

Comment: @ErikE Saying, "I didn't say this answer is slow, I just said that the things that the answer are doing is slow" is just a pointless statement.  They mean exactly the same thing.  Obviously no one things that you're referring to the speed of something else in the answer besides the execution of the code; it's a pointless clarification.  As for caching the information about the type *that's already done*.  There's nothing for you to cache.  One of the many reasons why reflection isn't nearly as slow as people seem to think it will be.

Comment: @Servy The answer is fine insofar as it goes. It is neither fast nor slow by itself. I can see that I have to post my own answer to show you. It is clear to me that you are far more offended than necessary. Will this help: I am very sorry that I didn’t qualify my statement about reflection. I am sorry for making it seem like I was slandering the writer of the answer. I am sorry for being a drive-by commenter. I should have said “... compared to direct method invocation, so if this is executed a lot you may need to cache the reflection method creation.”